# In the MATLAB mexFunction how do you assign GNU Scientific Library matrices and vectors to plhs?

Tags: c, matlab, mex

I have MATLAB code that I want to call the GNU Scientific Library (GSL) C library to compute the [singular value decomposition](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/linalg.html#c.gsl_linalg_SV_decomp) of a matrix.  Basically, I need to implement the [gateway MEX function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexfunction.html).  I see how to set the input variables, but how do I set the output variables?

Here is my code so far:

## build.m

```
mex -v -L/home/miran045/reine097/c-libs/lib/ -R2017b project_m.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

## call_c_from_matlab.m

```
A_data = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0];

[U, S, V] = project_m(4, 5, A_data);
```

## project_m_from_c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_linalg.h>

#include "mex.h"
    
void run_svd(const size_t M, const size_t N, double A_data[], gsl_matrix * B, gsl_matrix * V, gsl_vector * S, gsl_vector * work)
{
  gsl_linalg_SV_decomp(B, V, S, work);
}

static double
get_double(const mxArray *array_ptr)
{
    double *pr;
    pr = mxGetPr(array_ptr);
    double result = (double) *pr;
    
    return result;
}

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] ) {
    int i, j;

   /* You should put code here to check nrhs, nlhs, prhs[0], prhs[1], prhs[2] */

    int m = (int) get_double(prhs[0]);
    int n = (int) get_double(prhs[1]);
    double *mexArray =  mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
    int Bm, Bn; /* added */
   
  gsl_matrix * B;
  gsl_matrix * V;
  gsl_vector * S;
  gsl_vector * work;
  gsl_matrix_view A = gsl_matrix_view_array(mexArray, m, n);
  if (n > m) {
    Bm = n; Bn = m; /* added */
    work = gsl_vector_alloc(m);

    gsl_matrix_transpose_memcpy(B, &A.matrix);
  } else {
    Bm = m; Bn = n; /* added */
    work = gsl_vector_alloc(n);

    gsl_matrix_memcpy(B, &A.matrix);
  }

   plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( Bm, Bn, mxREAL );
   plhs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( Bn,  1, mxREAL );
   plhs[2] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( Bn, Bn, mxREAL );
   
   run_svd(m, n, mexArray, plhs[0], plhs[2], plhs[1], work);
   
   gsl_vector_free(work);
}
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
gsl: ../gsl/gsl_matrix_double.h:278: ERROR: first index out of range
Default GSL error handler invoked.
matlab&
[2] 130182
[1]   Killed                  matlab
reine097@native [/panfs/roc/groups/4/miran045/reine097] % MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
MATLAB: smart_ptr.cpp:82: matrix::unique_mxarray_ptr matrix::from_matlab(mxArray* const&): Assertion `Input to from_matlab must have temporary or local scope' failed.
matlab&
[3] 115869
[2]   Segmentation fault      (core dumped) matlab
reine097@native [/panfs/roc/groups/4/miran045/reine097] % MATLAB is selecting SOFTWARE OPENGL rendering.
reine097@native [/panfs/roc/groups/4/miran045/reine097] % gsl: svd.c:79: ERROR: length of workspace must match second dimension of matrix A
Default GSL error handler invoked.
matlab&
[4] 89615
[3]   Killed                  matlab
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code:

- You don't check that the inputs are exactly as expected (real, double, non-sparse, etc.)
- You are attaching memory allocated without MATLAB API functions to an mxArray
- You are freeing the memory behind the pointers right after you attach them to the mxArray
- You don't create the plhs[ ] mxArray variables before using them

Normally, when working with mex routines one would do the following in order:

- Check that inputs are exactly as expected
- Create the output plhs[ ] mxArray variables
- Get the pointers to the data areas of the plhs[ ] mxArray variables
- Pass these pointers to the calculation routines

In your case, maybe there is a reason you want to use the gsl_matrix_alloc( ) routine for your memory allocation instead of the MATLAB API memory allocation functions.  Fine, but if you do this then you will have to *copy* the result into the plhs[ ] mxArray data area.  You can't attach the pointer directly because that will screw up the MATLAB Memory Manager and lead to a crash downstream.  But in all cases you need to create the plhs[ ] mxArray variables first.  E.g., if we just go with your current memory allocation scheme you would need to copy the data:

*EDIT for gsl data copy*

```
/* Create MATLAB mxArray from gsl_vector */
mxArray *gslvector2MATLAB(gsl_vector *V)
{
    mxArray *mx;
    double *data, *target;
    size_t n, stride;
    if( V ) {
        n = V->size;
        data = V->data;
        stride = V->stride;
        mx = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(n,1,mxREAL);
        target = (double *) mxGetData(mx);
        while( n-- ) {
            *target++ = *data;
            data += stride;
        }
    } else {
        mx = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(0,0,mxREAL);
    }
    return mx;
}

/* Create MATLAB mxArray from gsl_matrix */
mxArray *gslmatrix2MATLAB(gsl_matrix *M)
{
    mxArray *mx;
    double *data, *target;
    size_t i, j, m, n;
    if( M ) {
        m = M->size1;
        n = M->size2;
        data = M->data;
        mx = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(m,n,mxREAL);
        target = (double *) mxGetData(mx);
        for( i=0; i<m; i++ ) {
            for( j=0; j<n; j++ ) {
                target[i+j*m] = data[j]; /* tranpose */
            }
            data += M->tda;
        }
    } else {
        mx = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(0,0,mxREAL);
    }
    return mx;
}

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] ) {
    int i;

   /* You should put code here to check nrhs, nlhs, prhs[0], prhs[1], prhs[2] */

    int m = (int) get_double(prhs[0]);
    int n = (int) get_double(prhs[1]);
    double *mexArray =  mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
   
  gsl_matrix * B;
  gsl_matrix * V;
  gsl_vector * S;
  gsl_vector * work;
  gsl_matrix_view A = gsl_matrix_view_array(mexArray, m, n);
  if (n > m) {
    B = gsl_matrix_alloc(n, m);
    V = gsl_matrix_alloc(m, m);
    S = gsl_vector_alloc(m);
    work = gsl_vector_alloc(m);

    gsl_matrix_transpose_memcpy(B, &A.matrix);
  } else {
    B = gsl_matrix_alloc(m, n);
    V = gsl_matrix_alloc(n, n);
    S = gsl_vector_alloc(n);
    work = gsl_vector_alloc(n);

    gsl_matrix_memcpy(B, &A.matrix);
  }

    run_svd(m, n, mexArray, B, V, S, work);
    
    nlhs = 3; // delete this line
    mxSetPr(plhs[0], B); // delete this line
    mxSetPr(plhs[1], S); // delete this line
    mxSetPr(plhs[2], V); // delete this line

    /* call custom routines to copy data as transpose */
    plhs[0] = gslmatrix2MATLAB(B);
    plhs[1] = gslvector2MATLAB(S);
    plhs[2] = gslmatrix2MATLAB(V);

  gsl_matrix_free(B);
  gsl_matrix_free(V);
  gsl_vector_free(S);
  gsl_vector_free(work);
}
```

I am not familiar with the gsl_matrix or gsl_vector types, so can't advise you how to copy the data noted above.  Generally, you could just get the data pointers from the gsl types and then memcpy the data.  You could avoid this data copy and increase the performance of your code if you followed the steps I outlined above and create the plhs[ ] variables first and then pass their data pointers directly to your svd routine.

Comment: Regarding this bit:

    /* add code here to copy from B to mxGetData(plhs[0]) */

I know how to get the i-th row and j-th column from B.  You do it like this:

     gsl_matrix_get(B, i, j).

But how do you set the i-th row and j-th column of mxGetData(plhs[0])?

Comment: I looked at the doc for the gsl vector and matrix types, and it looks like a simple structure with a field called "data" that is a pointer to double.  So it appears you could just do this:  memcpy(mxGetData(plhs[0]),B->data,Bm*Bn); and similarly for S and V.

Comment: Well, I read the gsl doc further and it appears matrices are stored in row-major order (like C). But MATLAB stores matrices in column-major order (like Fortran). So doing the memcpy( ) above will not work directly.  You will essentially need to transpose the matrix either in your C code or after you get it on the MATLAB side. Let me know if you need help with this part.

Comment: Note that if tda doesn't match size2 in the gsl matrix the underlying data will not be contiguous and you would have to copy the data in a loop row by row.

Comment: I could use some help with this part,  How do you set the i-th row and j-th column element of mxGetData(plhs[0])?

Comment: I rewrote it more in line with your suggestions.  Now I'm getting a crash.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230051/discussion-between-paul-reiners-and-james-tursa).